# Is there a way to enable custom autocomplete on all typed text in pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, pycharm, spell-checking

I'm new to Python and have installed the Pycharm IDE recently. In Microsoft Word, the inbuilt text autocorrect feature autocorrects text immediately after typing a space after the incorrect word.
For example, it would autocorrect 'teh' to 'the' instantaneously while typing.

Is there a similar feature or plugin in Pycharm that could perhaps expand, say 'pr' to 'print()', 'wo' to 'with open()' or other custom abbreviations upon typing.

I know we could perhaps type our abbreviations, save the python file, open that python file in a new one, convert its content into a string and run multiple find and replace operations on it. However, this would only run replace operations after the file is saved, not instantaneously after typing.

If this is not possible, is there any other Python IDE that offers this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pycharm has a Live Template feature that allows you to specify shortcuts that expand to code of your choice:

[image: Live Templates]

Expansion happens by pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key though, not on its own.

The only once I ever use is the `main` one (because `if __name__ == '__main__':` is a pain to type), so I don't have a lot of experience with them. They've worked well the few times I've used them though.